# Can I vmotion from VMware workstation?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-workstation

I love the idea of vmotion and know that I can move a VM from vSphere / ESX (or whatever I'm meant to call the server class hypervisor now).

But Can I do vMotion from a VMware workstation host?

Comment: Workstation does not support vMotion

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no vMotion in VMware Workstation.

There is the notion of *Upload* where you can connect to your vCenter server from Workstation itself and upload your local VMs to vCenter.

But that does not happen as a vMotion operation (i.e.: while the VM is running).